# C, Creating a 32 bit pointer to a 8 bit array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a buffer where each entry in the buffer is 8 bits in size:

```
uint8_t Buffer[10] = {0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0xF1,0xF2,0xF3,0xF4,0xF5,0xF6};
```

What I need to do is to create pointers to that array, for example 16 bit and 32 bit pointers. For example:

```
uint32_t *x;
x = Buffer;

uint32_t *y;
y = Buffer+4;

uint16_t *z;
z = Buffer+8;
```

Where each variable would then read from the array, for example:

```
x = 0x78563412
y = 0xf4f3f2f1
z = 0xf6f5
```

This works completely fine, the problem is that I'm getting warnings about incompatible pointer types. So I was wondering if there is an alternative way of doing this or if I'll just have to live with the warnings? Or am I simply doing this completely the wrong way?

Please note that this code will be executed on a single type of platform where the endianness is always the same and the size of data types is always the same.

Comment: You can get rid of the warnings by en explicit cast. Also you imply in your code that int is 32 bit, you might want to use `uint32_t` to be sure. You could also cast to an int* first, and then use `+1` instead of `+4`, which might look nicer (or use array syntax).

Comment: `char` is not necessarily 8 bits. Use `uint8_t` and other fixed-width types if you need fixed widths. That way you don't have to explain the lengths of your types. Also your code can invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Use proper marshalling/serialisation with bitshifts! There are plenty of questions about that already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should heed the warnings; what you're doing is undefined behavior. Type aliasing like that is undefined behavior, particularly since there is no guarantee that `Buffer` has the correct alignment such that it can be accessed as an `int`/`short`. If `Buffer` has the correct alignment, then you can just explicitly cast and it's okay (and the warning will go away).

You have two options:

One, you align the buffer as the larger of the two types. Be careful that your pointer arithmetic doesn't throw off the alignment:

```
#include <stdalign.h>

alignas(int) unsigned char Buffer[10] = {0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0xF1,0xF2,0xF3,0xF4,0xF5,0xF6};

unsigned int *x;
x = (unsigned int*)(Buffer);

unsigned int *y;
y = (unsigned int*)(Buffer+4);

unsigned short *z;
z = (unsigned short*)(Buffer+8);
```

Two, you create an `unsigned int`/`unsigned short` variable and then `memcpy` the bytes you're interested in into the variable:

```
unsigned int x;
memcpy(&x, Buffer, 4);

unsigned int y;
memcpy(&y, Buffer + 4, 4);

unsigned short z;
memcpy(&z, Buffer + 8, 2);
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to use up as little RAM space as possible. That's why I'm trying to store all values in a buffer which is regularly written to ROM memory, and then just point variables into that buffer.

I might be thinking this the wrong way. But basicly what I want to be able to do is that instead of doing something like Buffer[0]<<8 | Buffer[1]. I would rather have short x point to Buffer[0] and Buffer[1]

Comment: `char *` are the one exception to the effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule. However, the alignment issue is real. And other problems like endianess.

Comment: @gislibergur: I added a portion on alignment.

Comment: There is no `reinterpret_cast` in C.

Comment: @alk: D'oh. I switched to C++ mode... it's corrected now; thanks.

Comment: @Cornstalks Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Allocating the buffer via `malloc()` (e.g. dynamically) would guarantee the memory to be aligned for usage with with any type.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that it assumes a particular endianness of underlying hardware. Different computers will interpret a sequence of hex bytes

```
01 23 45 67
```

as eiter

```
01234567 or 67452301
```

Your program may compile and run on both systems, but since the result is hardware-specific, the compiler must warn you of the possibility.

The proper way of forcing a particular endianness is by using an array of integers, convert them using hton and ntoh functions, and set individual bytes either directly by casting a pointer to unsigned char*, or with memcpy.

Comment: You forgot about alignment and bit-width of the standard integer types.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a union

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union{

    uint8_t Buffer[10];
    struct{
        uint32_t x;
        uint32_t y;
        uint16_t z;
    };

}MYSTRUCT;


int main(){

    MYSTRUCT b = {0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0xF1,0xF2,0xF3,0xF4,0xF5,0xF6};

    printf("x=%#x y=%#x z=%#x\n",b.x,b.y,b.z);

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee a `struct` will not include padding bytes. Left alone the other proplems.

Comment: well I'd usually use something like '__attribute__((packed))' depending on the compiler

Comment: Neither `__attribute__` nor `#pragma packed` or similar are standard C or guaranteed by a compiler. Also they will generate massive code-overhead on some platforms as every access to a longer variable will be split into multiple byte-reads to allow missalignment. Worst case is they result in crash/wrong execution for unaligned accesses. Not to forget about the other problems. IOW: Just don't!

Comment: Nope, its not standard C - that's why I didn't put it in the code. On some platforms it will generate a massive overhead but the thing is on those platforms you probably won't be needing to mess with a single buffer holding your integer variables (RAM conservation was mentioned and not having fewer instructions or being faster). I know its not the most portable C code but similar stuff like this is very handy when working with, in example, an 8 bit PIC.

Comment: PIC and other 8 bitters typically don't have alignment requirements. On these platforms proper marshalling with bitshifts typically don't add any overhead with a good compiler compared to the non-standard casting. Problematic are e.g. ARM Cortex-M, which either require aligned accesses or use non-optimal accesses (e.g. splitting up unaligned word-reads to three 1/2/1 byte reads). Either way it is a bad idea. Typically you do ther serialisation once and then work with the wider types, so it is a bad idea to have the penalty for the majority of accesses. Also one does not want to have ...

Comment: ... this `union` on all layers of the data-handling, but only in the low-level driver. You can write such code very well for small systems, too. And still **you forget about the other issues**